# Delete a row from listview xamarin

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a activity in which there are some buttons and a listview.each rows of the listview has a delete button which i'm intend to delete the row whenever the user click the delete button.
i'm using a custom adapter so here is my getview method:

```
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            convertView = menuActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.OrderItemLayout, null);
            ImageButton btn = convertView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btn_del);
            btn.Tag = position;
            btn.Click += btn_Click;
            return convertView;
        }

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _lstOrder.RemoveAt((int)((sender as ImageButton)).Tag);
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

but the problem is that when i click the delete button the listview doesn't refresh so the row that was deleted is still there but it will gone if i go back and then come to the activity again.
how can I solve this problem so after i delete a row the listview refresh?
thank you

Comment: have to remove particular position from your list and also from your arraylistadapter and then you need to refresh the list using NotifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: i have to do this in the adapter or in my activity? i used the NotifyDataSetChanged() in the click event

Comment: Do within the onclickListener in your adapter

Comment: can yo share the code? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a common arraylist

```
ArrayList<GeterSetterClass> comn_arylist = new ArrayList<GeterSetterClass>();
```

Customized addapter setting

```
custdet_adapter adapter = new custdet_adapter(this,comn_arylist);

listview.setAdapter(adapter);
listview.invalidateViews();
```

Customized Adapter class

```
public static class custdet_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<GeterSetterClass> cust_arrayList;
    private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

    public custdet_adapter(Context context,
                ArrayList<GeterSetterClass> list_details) {
            cust_arrayList = list_details;
            l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
            return cust_arrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
            return cust_arrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
             if (convertView == null) {
                 convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutname_struct,null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txt_custname = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.txt_mobno = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.txt_custname.setText(cust_arrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.txt_mobno.setText(cust_arrayList.get(position).getunitcd());

        holder.txt_custname.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                comn_arylist.remove(position);
                listview.invalidateViews();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_custname;
        TextView txt_mobno;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i think your code is in java and i'm writing with xamarin which is in C#.and i did all of this and how do you call            listview.invalidateViews(); in the adapter class?

Comment: you can use notifydatasetchanged() instead of invalidateviews()

Comment: did you read my question? i have a method to delete and then i called this notifydatasetchanged() but nothing happens